# ADF and EBS, ICX SESSION is not valid

Tags: oracle, session, oracle-adf, session-management, oracle-ebs

I'm trying to launch ADF sample Session Management App that is provided in Oracle  DOC.974949.1 , with EBS 12.2.6. I have done everything that is written in the Oracle doc. Still, session management is not working. When I start the EBS function responsible for launching sample app, I am redirected to EBS logon page. According to the use case from Oracle doc., it means that EBS user is not authenticated. I suspect that cookie which has session attributes cannot be correctly validated. Someone had that problem too? Could anyone suggest what should be done in order to launch the app?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know, but a couple things to check:

- You need to be logged in via the standard EBS login
- The EBS session cookies need to be scoped broadly enough to cover the new host
- The DBC file associated with the Java SDK needs to be generated correctly
  (see the Java SDK doc)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am logging-in  via user that was created, like it is instructed in doc. The DBC file looks fine also, I have checked connection like it is instructed in - https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=272706737651128&id=2082683.1&displayIndex=7&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=m4yx6w51i_4 . Could you say something more about "The EBS session cookies need to be scoped broadly enough to cover the new host" ?

Comment: By "The EBS session cookies need to be scoped broadly enough to cover the new host", do you mean that my icx_session cookie must have the same domain like my EBS? e.g.: 
my external app domain - icx_session_cookie: adfTest.abc.company
EBS domain JSESSIONID: ebsApp.abc.company 
or like
my external app domain - icx_session_cookie: adfTest.ebsApp.abc.company
EBS domain JSESSIONID: ebsApp.abc.company

Comment: Yes.  The EBS session cookie (usually named after your SID) needs to be scoped so that the host that is running the ADF application receives the EBS session cookie.   In your example you may have your ebs on ebs.abc.company and adf on adf.abc.company - you want your cookie scoped to abc.company.   Note that in 12.2.6 this is configurable.

Easiest way to check this is correct is to look at the headers, and make sure the icx cookie is being sent to the adf server.